# How to populate a second view controller with information when a row is selected on a UIPickerView

Tags: json, swift, uipickerview

I am creating my first app and I want data to be displayed in a second view controller when an item is selected in a UI Picker.

When the search bar on my first view controller is clicked, I would like a UI Picker to appear.  The UI Picker will display country names.  The UI Picker will populate the search bar with the selected country name.  When a button is pressed, I would like to perform a segue to the second view controller which will then be populated with the information about the selected country.  I am trying to develop my first app and I can't seem to find any tutorials on this exact subject.  How do I get a UI Picker to display when the search bar is selected?  How do I pass information over to the second view controller based on the selected picker row?

Below is the code that I have been able to come up with on my own.  Otherwise, I'm stumped.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var countryPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var goButtonPressed: UIButton!

    var countryName : [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.countryPicker.delegate = self
        self.countryPicker.dataSource = self

        countryName = ["Australia", "Bolivia", "Croatia", "Denmark", "Estonia", "France", "Germany", "Hungary"]
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return countryName.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        print (countryName[row])
        return countryName[row]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

First, declare a variable in your first View Controller and assign to it the first value of the pickerView:

```
var selectedCountryName: String = countryName[0]
```

Then, declare the following method to capture the picker view selection and assign it to the previously declared variable:

```
// Capture the picker view selection
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent 
component: Int) {
     selectedCountryName = countryName[row]
}
```

Then, inside your second view controller, declare the same selectedCountryName variable:

```
var selectedCountryName: String = country[0]
```

Finally, pass the selected country name from the first to the second view controller inside the first view controller's prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        destinationVC.selectedCountryName = selectedCountryName 
    }
```